# Error running tests with Conda and Tox

Tags: python, conda, tox

I am having trouble running tests with Tox while having virtual environments created with Conda. The steps to reproduce the error are below.

Download the repository (it is small) and `cd` to it:

```
git clone https://github.com/opensistemas-hub/osbrain.git
cd osbrain
```

Create the virtual environment with Conda:

```
conda create -n asdf python=3.5
source activate asdf
pip install tox
```

Try to run the tests (note that Python 3.5 is the only Python interpreter set in the `tox.ini` file):

```
tox
```

I would expect Tox to be able to use the Python 3.5 interpreter available in the Conda virtual environment to run the tests. However, instead, I am getting an error:

```
ERROR: The executable ~/osbrain/.tox/py35/bin/python3.5 is not 
functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/usr' (should be '~/osbrain/.tox/py35')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
Running virtualenv with interpreter ~/.miniconda3/envs/asdf/bin/python3.5
```

My question is: why am I getting that error and how can I avoid this? (i.e.: how could I run the tests locally for this project and using Tox?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to work around this by [installing virtualenv](https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/issues/1139) through conda:

`conda install virtualenv`

It's not recommended to use virtualenv yourself (stick with conda environments). However, when tox looks for the package internally it will at least find a compatible version.

Comment: Thank you so much. Install virtualenv by conda solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Virtualenv and conda/conda-env do not currently play nice together.  See https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes/issues/1139 and https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/conda/63B0jnPR-V4.

UPDATE

Also related: https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/tox/issues/273/support-conda-envs-when-using-miniconda